# C++ Class Destructor Using New Value Rather Than Actual Value

Tags: c++

How come this sets the value BEFORE it destructs rather than destructing on the classes previous value (5)?

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

class TestClass {
public:
    int intval = 0;
    TestClass(int pos)  {
        intval = pos;
    }
    ~TestClass() {
        printf("Deleted! %i\n",intval);
    }
};

int main()
{
    TestClass a(5);
    a = TestClass(234);//should print out "Deleted! 5"
    printf("Test\n");
}
```

Output:

```
Deleted! 234
Test
Deleted! 234
```

Comment: Please don't show images of text, least of all code. Copy-paste the code *as text* into the question. Same with text output. And please refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: As a hint about your problem: `a` isn't destructed until the program ends! When you assign to an object, it doesn't destruct the object first.

Comment: Okay hmm well then why is "Test" being printed after the destruction of a(5)? That doesn't make sense if it isn't destructed until the program ends. I am curious why it doesn't destruct the object before the assignment though... Doesn't really make sense to destruct it after it has assigned it new values.

Comment: Because a has never gone out of scope and therefore its destructor is not invoked. The line a = TestClass(234); results in the temporary creation of a TestClass instance whose contents are then copied into the existing instance of a. The temporary TestClass then goes out of scope and its destructor is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code shown you create *two* objects, and both are destructed but at different times.

First you have

```
TestClass a(5);
```

This object `a` will live on until the scope ends (which happens at the end of the function). This is the *second* output `Deleted! 234` you see.

The second object you create is when you do

```
a = TestClass(234);
```

What happens here is that `TestClass(234)` creates a *temporary* object. This temporary object is the used for a copy-assignment to `a`, and then the temporary object is destructed. This destruction is the *first* output `Deleted! 234` you see.

---

To explain

```
a = TestClass(234);
```

a little more, its somewhat roughly equivalent to

```
{
    TestClass temporary_object(234);
    a.operator=(temporary_object);
    // temporary_object ends its life here and the destructor will be called
}
```

The full code, with comments where objects are created and destructed

```
int main()
{
    TestClass a(5);  // Create object a
    a = TestClass(234);  // Create temporary object, temporary object is destructed
    printf("Test\n");

    // As scope ends, the life-time of object a also ends, and a is destructed
}
```